# A simple 5x5 crossword

Tags: crosswords

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #14: Think inside the (very small) box!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7497/monthly-topic-challenge-14-think-inside-the-very-small-box).</sub>

---

**A simple crossword:**

[image: 5x5 American Crossword]

**Across:**
1: Mormons, officially
4: Proceed, say
6: Correo _____ (Spanish mail stamp)
8: Spanish 3 + 3
9: Common chess rating

**Down:**
1: JFK alternative
2: Some deer
3: "Yes _____!"
5: Astronaut Armstrong
7: Bear: sp.

This is my first crossword. It's nothing huge, but I hope you enjoy!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the completed crossword grid:

> [image]

Comment: Oh, rot13(gur nvecbeg, abg gur crefba). Duh.